# How to ng-repeat over two models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I am very new to Angular, and am looking for a clean solution for an issue:

I have a  element called "SelectedList" that has two show a list of elements that have been made 'active' in another container. Now this container has two tabs Tab1 and Tab2, populated from $scope.model1 and $scope.model2. Now if an element Element1 in Tab1 is selected, I need to add it to "SelectedList". If I then select Element2 from Tab2, then Element2 has to appear in "SelectedList", under Element1.

Now, I could possibly create a temporary model combining $scope.model1 and $scope.model2 called $scope.selectedList and do

```
<ul id="SelectedList" ng-repeat="listItem in selectedList">...</ul>
```

But I'm looking to see if there is a cleaner method that satisfies two-way data binding, something like:

```
<ul id="SelectedList" ng-repeat="listItem in model1+model2">...</ul>
```

Is there a better solution to this? Is there maybe a completely different approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your lists are arrays you can use their `concat` method to join them:

```
    <ul ng-repeat="item in arrayList1.concat(arrayList2)">...</ul>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, concat does not seem to be working as they are not simple arrays :( Any other suggestions?

Comment: if they are not simple arrays, it is not possible to find a general solution that would work for all kinds of objects. In this case a temporary object wich contains elements of both lists is in my opinion not a bad solution.